# OpenGL Linux poor performance nVidia

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, nvidia

I'm developing an openGL game for a school project and I'm having performance issues. I'm on Ubuntu, using eclipse indigo 8.0.2 with a makefile project.

My PC is a laptop with double GPU (integrated Intel and dedicated nVidia), so I had the doubt that the GPU used was the integrated one and not the dedicated one.

I tested the graphics with glxgears. The result was 60fps presumably capped. I then used glxinfo to find out the renderer device and found out that the integrated card was being used indeed.

After some research, I found out that with the latest nVidia drivers nvidia prime was released (the new double GPU management). So I succesfully installed the last drivers with nvidia prime.

After this, i tried again glxgears and now i got values around 10000fps, and also glxinfo showed that the dedicated GPU was being used.

I also checked the GPU utilization while running glxgears to triple check that, and the utilization was on 100%. This confirmed what glxinfo showed me.

Now, the problem is, when I executed my openGL game after installing the new drivers I got no preformance improvement.

I checked the GPU utilization while running my game and it was about 20%.

How is that possible that glxgears uses 100% of GPU (and runs at 10000fps instead of 60fps) while my game stays under 20% and runs at ~20fps as it was running on the integrated GPU?

I think 20fps are too few considering my GPU (nvidia gt555m) is able to run games way more complex than my project game (it's just a racing simulator with a motorcycle and few other objects, like some trees, the track, low res environment around) at even 40+ fps.

I hope I explained my problem and someone has any idea about. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How is that possible that glxgears uses 100% of GPU (and runs at 10000fps instead of 60fps) while my game stays under 20% and runs at ~20fps as it was running on the integrated GPU?

Your game is CPU bound. Time to profile your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What you mean by "profile your code" ?

Comment: @Drakem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)